# Sorting list by taillength and alphabetically

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist

I am supposed to write an algorithm for sorting a list.
The list should be sorted by taillength. If two of the dogs on the list have the same taillength, they are supposed to be sorted alphabetically.

I have a method called getTailLength which returns the taillength of the dog.
This what I have so far for the sorting algorithm:

```java
public void sortByName(ArrayList<Dog> allDogs) {
    for (int i = 1; i < allDogs.size(); i++) {
        String currentDogName = allDogs.get(i).getName();
        
        // Dog dog = allDogs.get(i).getName();
        // int currentDogNameIndex = i;
        int j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 0 && currentDogName
                .compareTo(allDogs.get(j).getName()) < 0) {
            allDogs.set(j + 1, allDogs.get(j));
            j--;
        }
        allDogs.set(j + 1, currentDogName);
    }
}
```

```java
public void sortDogs(ArrayList<Dog> allDogs) {
    for (int i = 1; i < allDogs.size(); i++) {
        double currentMinTail = allDogs.get(i).getTailLength();
        int currentMinTailIndex = i;

        for (int j = i - 1; j < allDogs.size(); j++) {
            if (currentMinTail > allDogs.get(j).getTailLength()) {
                Collections.swap(allDogs, i, j);
            } else if (currentMinTail == allDogs.get(i).getTailLength()) {
                sortByName(allDogs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is with this line of code

```java
allDogs.set(j + 1, currentDogName);
```

I'm not sure what to change here, since it says Dog is required but I am comparing strings and not dogs since I am comparing names?

Comment: This looks overly complicated. Have you considered using the Comaparable interface?

Comment: So I imagine instead of creating a ```String currentDogName``` you could just use the dog object itself, but every time using the current dog object to compare its name, use ```currentDog.getName()```

Comment: So, I would say get  all the tail length of all the dogs, put it in a collection, sort it, and then  call the SortByName method, think that will make your job a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to give a instance of Dog to `allDogs.set(index, Dog)`.

You compare Strings, but you still sort Dogs.

You get `currentDogName` by using `allDogs.get(i).getName();` i will not change in the routine so just replace `allDogs.set(j + 1, currentDogName);` with `allDogs.set(j + 1, allDogs.get(i));`

In general your functions seem very messy. Working the whole array in the helper function ´sortByName´ will probably result in errors.

You should do one of the following instead:

1. Use ´Collections.sort()´ and the ´Comparable´ interface
2. Sort the array by tail length and then iterate it again to sort all dogs with the same tail length

Answer (score 0):

If it is not an exercise, the right way is to replace `sortDogs()` with the below single line:

```
allDogs.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Dog::getTailLength)
                       .thenComparing(Dog::getName));
```